# Spinner values outsized, not all visible, and no scroll bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-xml

When I click on my spinners, they show the values I have assigned to them, but they are not only outsized (I'd prefer them to just "hang" off of the spinners as combo box items do in desktop apps), but also not all of the values display - they are presumably "there" but are below and out of sight. I'm putting my xml and java below:

XML:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerTimeValsNN"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

From Strings.xml:

1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10
    15
    20
    30
    40
    45

..okay, the above stripped out all the xml and just left the vals...

Java:

```
spinnerTimeValsNN = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTimeValsNN);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterTimeNN = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
this, R.array.timevalsnn_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapterTimeNN.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerTimeValsNN.setAdapter(adapterTimeNN);
```

Comment: It's possibly a little better if I change simple_spinner_dropdown_item to be simple_spinner_item in _both_ cases.

Answer (score 2):

I run into this same issue when trying to open a spinner located at the bottom of a layout of a DialogFragment.

There is a related open issue in Google's Issue Tracker, and you can check its progress here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149041222

I tried lots of changes and I haven't found any solution except that this error only happen when spinner shows as drop down mode. It doesn't happen when shown as a dialog.

Therefore a workaround is to set:

```
    <Spinner
        ...
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making your spinner a Variable

Example:
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

Comment: Why that would matter I don't grok, but I'll give it a go.